# Pass Nothing from Javascript to VBScript in IE9

Tags: javascript, vbscript, internet-explorer-9

I have a framework written in VBScript. Inside some function in this framework, a parameter of the function is checked for *Nothing* in an *If* statement and then some actions are executed.

Code that uses the framework is written in JavaScript. So I need to pass *Nothing* to the function to perform some actions. In [Internet Explorer 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_8) and earlier versions, the following approach worked:

```html
<script type="text/vbscript">
    Function Test(val)
        If (IsNull(val)) Then
            Test = "Null"
        ElseIf (IsObject(val)) Then
            If (val Is Nothing) Then
                Test = "Nothing"
            End If
        End If
    End Function

    Dim jsNothing
    Set jsNothing = Nothing
    msgBox(Test(jsNothing))
    msgBox(Test(Null))
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    alert(Test(jsNothing));
</script>
```

In Internet Explorer before version 9, the output will: Nothing, Null, Nothing.

In [Internet Explorer 9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_9): Nothing, Null, Null.

How can I pass Nothing from JavaScript to VBScript in Internet Explorer 9?

There is an example of a framework function. I can not change it, because it is widely used in application.

```vbnet
Function ExampleFunction(val)
    If (val Is Nothing) Then
        ExampleFunction = 1
    Else
        ExampleFunction = 0
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Small sidenote: VBScript [doesn't have short-circuited logical operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8zy95hw%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), so the statement `IsObject(val) And val Is Nothing` will still result in an error.  You'll have to split it into a nested If.

Comment: I closed this out as too localized for you. In the future, you can just flag to let us know :)

Comment: Does VBScript have And Also? I know VB.Net has it. As lame as that is, at least it will allow for short-circuiting.

Comment: @vbullinger: No, it has not lazy logic. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2004/07/15/184431.aspx -Eric Lippert's article.

Answer (score 18):

Unfortunately, you are probably stuck here - JavaScript does not have a "Nothing" equivalent. See [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/10/01/53128.aspx) for more information.

However, the following may work. In your VBScript code, create a function called "GetNothing" that returns "Nothing". In your JavaScript code, use "var jsNothing = GetNothing()". It comes from [this article](http://www.siteexperts.com/forums/viewConverse.asp?d_id=14844&start=1).

Comment: ***Both links*** are ***broken***. The first one redirects to a generic page and for the second *"Hmm. We’re having trouble finding that site. We can’t connect to the server at www.siteexperts.com."* is reported.

Comment: OK, the OP has left the building (*"Last seen more than 2 years ago"*)

Answer (score 4):

I don't have access to Internet Explorer right now, so I can't test this, but try to write a function like this:

```
<script type="text/vbscript">
  Function CallWithNulls(fn, arg1, arg2, arg3)
    If (isNull(arg1)) arg1 = Nothing
    If (isNull(arg2)) arg2 = Nothing
    If (isNull(arg3)) arg3 = Nothing
    fn(arg1, arg2, arg3)
  End Function
  Function IsNothing(arg1, arg2, arg3)
     return arg1 is Nothing
  End Function
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  alert(CallWithNulls(IsNothing, null, 1, 2));
</script>
```

Of course, I don't know if VBScript allows calling functions like that... and you'd have to deal with more/fewer arguments.

Comment: It's a nice workaround. But this question is already 3 years dead. And I wish VBScript to be dead too :-) Thank's for effort and catch the upvote.

Comment: I wasn't trying to fix the problem (since I saw you'd already found a better solution), it was just an interesting question and I thought I'd give it a stab. Thanks for the upvote!

Comment: VBScript continues to be the scripting engine that powers some of HP's products, so it indeed should not die. Yet.

Answer (score 0):

Use a value such as zero or even a negative number. That would allow for you to simply use falsy evaluations, and then you don't have to worry about different browsers and their quirks in evaluating the `NULL` object.

Comment: Thanks for an answer but problem is in framework. It was written long ago and is used widely in large application and I can not change just it. I added to question example of a function of framework that called from javascript.

Answer (score 0):

As an example, something like this will work, but if the browser is [Internet Explorer 11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_11#Internet_Explorer_11) or later you will need the 'meta' tag.

```
<html>

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=10">
        <title>Pass JavaScript to VBScript</title>

        <script>
            var val = "null";

            window.alert("Test: " +  val);
        </script>

        <script type="text/vbscript">

            PassNothing(val)

            Sub PassNothing(value)
                If LCase(value) = "null" Then
                    MsgBox "Java passed 'null' so VBScript = 'Nothing'"
                Else
                    Msgbox "Nothing received"
                End If
            End Sub

        </script>

    </head>

</html>
```